# Using regex in second series.str.replace() argument

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm working with a DataFrame with a `year` column with the following format:

```
  year
  2015
2015-2016
  2016
```

I want to replace strings like '2015-2016' with just '2015' using regex. I tried something like this:

```
df['year']=df['year'].str.replace('[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4}','[0-9]{4}')
```

But that doesn't work. I know I could do smething like:

```
df['year']=df['year'].str.replace('\-[0-9]{4}','')
```

But sometimes you need something more flexible. Is there any way to keep a portion of the match in the regex or is this one the standard approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to keep the first year, and all years have 4 digits, use:

```
df['year'] = df.year.str.extract('(\d{4})')
>>> df
   year
0  2015
1  2015
2  2016
```

If you want to keep the first year before any `-`, use:

```
df['year'] = df.year.str.split('-').str[0]

>>> df
   year
0  2015
1  2015
2  2016
```

Comment: That exctarct function was something I should have already known, quite useful ! Thanks sacul

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the good year in parenthesis and refer to it in your replacement with `\1`:

```
df['year'].str.replace(r'([0-9]{4})\-[0-9]{4}', r'\1')
```

Or you can make parenthesis around the good year into a non-capturing positive lookbehind assertion with `?<=` and then the replacement string will be blank because only `\-[0-9]{4}` was matched (but only when preceded by `[0-9]{4}`).

```
df['year'].str.replace(r'(?<=[0-9]{4})\-[0-9]{4}', '')
```

Comment: First time I hear about lookaround assertions. Do you know any site where there's a good and understandable explanation of how they work? The explanations I've found haven't been very helpful to really understand the difference between negative/positive and ahead/behind

Comment: @JuanC: Here's a [short explanation](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) and a [longer one](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) on lookaround assertions.